# Freeradius showing incorrect number of online users vs NAS

Tags: mysql, freeradius, radius

**Scenario:**
Freeradius server 2.2.8 as billing system on Ubuntu Server, 
NAS is Mikrotik Router ccr1036 v 6.42.4

**Problem:**
on NAS i can see 900 active/online users, where as on freeradius I see 500 sessions (where acctstop time is NULL)

I use following query to calculate online number of users in FR.

```
mysql -uroot -s -e "use radius; select * from radacct  WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL;" |wc -l
```

I tried to disconnect all users on NAS, clear all sessions from freeradius, users reconnect fine, but still number of users on NAS vs freeradius doesnt matches. What should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fundamental issue with the fact that RADIUS is a lossy protocol.  If a user goes offline, and for some reason, the RADIUS server doesn't receive the `Acct-Status-Type=Stop` packet, then the session will be permanently marked as open.

If you use the SQL queries from FreeRADIUS v3, you'll see they have an `AcctUpdateTime` field.  This `AcctUpdateTime` field is set to `NOW()` every time a session is changed.

https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/mods-config/sql/main/mysql/queries.conf#L332

The purpose of this field is to make it easy for external scripts to go in and correct sessions which are obviously stale, by looking at when the session was last updated.

If you want to fix this, I'd either updated to FreeRADIUS v3.0.x (2.2.8 hasn't been supported for a while now), or use the v3.0.x schema and queries (they should mostly work).

Then just run a query every 10 minutes to updates rows with a `NULL` `AcctStopTime`, where the difference between `NOW()` and `AcctUpdateTime` is `>` `<NAS Interim Interval>` `*` `2`, setting `AcctStopTime` to `NOW()`.

For this to work, Interim-Updates will need to be enabled on your NAS.  These are Accounting-Requests sent periodically from the NAS to update things like traffic counters, but in this case, they can also be used as useful heartbeat messages.

If you can't figure out where the static config option for this is on your NAS, it can sometimes be enabled by returning the `Acct-Interim-Interval` attribute in  your `Access-Accept`, which'll specify the interim interval in seconds.

Comment: Dear Mr Arran, Appreciate your quick reply. I am using lastupdate column in radacct already along with the bash script that checks for session whose accounting have not been received from last 10 minutes and close it. but problem is NAS have more users vs users online in freeradius, the difference goes high some time.

Comment: mysql -uroot -pSQLPASS -s --skip-column-names -e "use radius; UPDATE radacct SET acctstoptime = NOW(), acctterminatecause = 'SCRIPT ACTION' WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL AND lastupdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)";

Comment: I have made a bash script which does following,
> get active user from FR
> get active user from Mikrotik PPP Active users , now it check difference between both lists, whatever extra users it finds, it goes to mikrotik via ssh and forcefully disconnects them, but some users are created locally in mikrotik ppp section, they gets disconnect too, need to find some way to check this.

Comment: there might be an option to enable RADIUS accounting for the local users too, many NAS allow that

Comment: If NAS and Radius communication disconnects BUT users are online in NAS, Radius will close all active sessions after 10 minutes (by our check stale script which checks lastupdate column in radacct, and because script will think NAS is offline it closes sessions to avoid false sessions/sim checks errors).

Afterwards communication restores & NAS sends already connected users accounting packets to RADIUS, FR will discards them because there are no active session in RADACCT that matches NAS sent acct session ID's.  If this is correct, then what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Don't actively try and determine the state of sessions.  Do what I suggested in my original answer.